# C# Workflow Custom Activity with a string-combobox in the PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, propertygrid

i want to use a string-combobox in the propertygrid of a custom activity in .NET Workflow Foundation.

While the combobox in the custom activity designer works fine and is bind to the activity properties, the property grid combobox does not bind to the activtity.

```
    public class PropertyGridStringComboBox : PropertyValueEditor
{
    public PropertyGridStringComboBox()
    {
        try
        {
            this.InlineEditorTemplate = new DataTemplate();

            FrameworkElementFactory stack = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
            stack.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

            FrameworkElementFactory comboBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));

            Binding binding = new Binding()
            {
                Path = new PropertyPath("Config"),
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
            };
            comboBox.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, SubnetConfigContainer.GetConfigNames());
            comboBox.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, binding);
            stack.AppendChild(comboBox);

            this.InlineEditorTemplate.VisualTree = stack;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
}
```

I found the hint, that "FrameworkElementFactory" is marked depreciatated. But how to do it correctly?

This is the corrosponding activity.

```
[Designer(typeof(ConfigSelectorActivityDesigner))]
public sealed class ConfigSelectorActivity : ActivityBase
{
    public string Config { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        SubnetConfigContainer.Instance.SelectedConfig = this.Config;
    }

    static ConfigSelectorActivity()
    {
        AttributeTableBuilder builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();
        builder.AddCustomAttributes(typeof(ConfigSelectorActivity), "Config", new EditorAttribute(typeof(PropertyGridStringComboBox), typeof(PropertyValueEditor)));
        MetadataStore.AddAttributeTable(builder.CreateTable());
    }

    public static void RegisterMetaData(AttributeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.AddCustomAttributes(typeof(ConfigSelectorActivity), new DesignerAttribute(typeof(ConfigSelectorActivityDesigner)));
    }
}
```

The ItemsSource is of type `List<string>`. But the binding in PropertyGridStringComboBox doesn't work.

Could anyone please show me how to get it to work or an working example (.NET 4.6.2).

Thanks in advance
Tucca

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

The Path have to be set to "Value" (at "new PropertyPath").

```
Binding binding = new Binding()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("Value"),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
        };
```